# Extracting email address from LinkedIn for a csv file of names in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, tidyverse, fuzzy-search

I hope everyone is doing alright.

I have a CSV file containing the  `first and last names`   of a company's clients.
I'd like to see which client  `has a LinkedIn account` . Also, export their  `email address`  if they have an account.
so my idea output would be like this:

```
first name   last name   have a LinkedIn    email address
  x              y            no              NA
  Z              T            yes          zzzttt123@live.com
```

I code in R and I wonder if there is any tidy method for scraping data in this context.
Thank you, everyone.

Best,

Comment: @akrun, I can't share the real names due to confidentiality issues, but you could fabricate any names for the exercise, my CSV file has 2387 rows containing both first and last names. I hope it helps

Comment: Would you be okay to use an api from `Rlinkedin` to search and extract i.e. `search.results <- searchPeople(token=in.auth, first_name="Michael", last_name="Piccirilli")`

Comment: pessimistically speaking, be prepared to harvest multiple to many entries for any common combination of first/last names - verifying which against your client base (by affiliation, location etc.) might become a manual nightmare (if not getting you into trouble with LinkedIn's use policy anyway).

Comment: @I_O, I know most of them live in the US and I can assume a state for them. is there any solution that you can propose?

Comment: @akrun, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Alex you can check the documentation in Rlinkedin.  It needs a token, which you can get by following the instructions and then run the searchPeople in a loop by loop over each row and collect output in a `list`.  I am not sure whether it returns email id or not

Comment: @akrun thanks I will check and keep you posted!

Comment: Alex: accessing the LinkedIn API via the {Rlinkedin} package @akrun discovered (kudos!) is IMO definitely the way to go. Should save you tedious webscraping.

Comment: @I_O, thank you both, I will work on it and will get back here. Thanks again